# Why was a Smurf at the final battle if no Smurf arcade game exists?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-smurfs, pixels

In *Pixels*, a Smurf appears amongst all of the video game enemies at the final battle.  According to the film, the game footage sent in the space probe was from the 1980's arcade challenge.

According to my research, the only video game with Smurfs at the time was *"Smurf: Rescue in Gargamel's Castle"*, which was only produced for home consoles (*The ColecoVision* and later, the *Atari 2600*).  Neither of these consoles was shown or referred-to during the arcade challenge; neither were Smurfs themselves.

So, how / why was there a Smurf with the rest of the arcade-style attackers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Between battles, the aliens address Earth in the form of icons from the 1980's, including President Ronald Reagan, Hall and Oates, and Max Headroom.  We must conclude that additional, non-game video footage from the era was included in the space probe.  It can be assumed that an episode or clips from the popular 1980's *"The Smurfs"* cartoon might have been sent alongside other footage.  Therefore, it can be concluded that the aliens decided a cartoon Smurf was appropriate to include in the final battle.

Answer (score 2):

The movie was made for entertainment purposes, it is not a historical reference for video games in the 80's; as such, there are many continuity errors in the movie:

- The only version of a Smurfs game in '82 when said video was sent to space was a ColecoVision and Atari 2600 verision
- Q*Bert didn't hit arcades till October '82
- Paper Boy, who appears in final battle, didn't show up till '85
- Arkanoid, which destroyed the Taj Mahal, was '86
- Duck Hunt from the final battle first appeared on console in August of '82
- Tetris came out '84.
- A man was dressed as Karate Kid at the '82 championship; Karate Kid was released in '84.
- Max Headroom first appeared on MTV in '85
- The scene of Hall and Oats is from MTV in '86

Comment: By the time the aliens arrive and begin hostilities, they will have had plenty of time to investigate further, perhaps picking up terrestrial transmissions from the eighties and watching them while *en route* to Earth?

Answer (score -2):

I did research and they wanted to have other types of things from the 1980's to be in the fight, so maybe like the guy on top said, they sent up footage of the smurfs

Comment: It'd be good if you include sources, supporting your answer.

Comment: "I did research" - no offence, but anyone could *say* this. Please include your research so that your post can be judged objectively.